# Wrapped hexagon topology

Tags: general-topology

When a square is wrapped at the edges, obtains a torus.
Is it possible to do the same for a hexagon?

What is the
**shape**/topology of **wrapping a hexagon**?

[image: rectangle wrapped to torus]
[image: hexagon]

Note: I was just reading this https://github.com/aichallenge/aichallenge/wiki/Ants-Problem-Description
and came up with this question.
I'm a physicist.

Comment: fyi if you take a $4g$-gon and identify sides $ababcdcd...$ you get a genus $g$ surface

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's still a torus, lol - just with a 180° twist relative to the square-wrapped version:

[image: from http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/Victor/part1.htm]

Image source: [http://www.math.cornell.edu/~mec/Winter2009/Victor/part1.htm](http://www.math.cornell.edu/%7Emec/Winter2009/Victor/part1.htm)

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I wanted. I didn't realize that the tube should be twisted before connecting the ends.

Comment: What makes the difference between a square and a hexagonal torus? Does it e.g. affect to way [how to draw $K_{3,3}$ on a torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3336725/two-or-three-faces-of-k-3-3-on-the-torus?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Comment: @draks... Since the hexagon has threefold symmetry (actually more) I would assume torus constructed from a hexagon would better exhibit how to draw the $K_{3,3}$ (I mean you get a torus either way though).

Comment: See also [What surface do we get by joining the opposite edges of a hexagon?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1978562/284619)