# Can a regular hexagon be wrapped up in four dimensional space without distortion?

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I know from this answer that hexagonal space is topologically equivalent to a torus (and therefore to square space):
[Wrapped hexagon topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53454/wrapped-hexagon-topology)

My question is, if we allow a regular hexagon to exist in four-dimensional space, can we fold it up so opposite sides touch, and angles, distances, and areas are not distorted on the hexagon?

Comment: As Alex' answer points out, it's not possible to do this for a trivial reason. But if we glue opposite edges, we get a Riemann surface isometric to the flat torus, and this surface can be isometrically embedded in $\Bbb R^4$.

Answer (score 1):

No. For instance, if the opposite sides touch, then distance between a point close to the midpoint of one side and a point close to the midpoint of the other side collapses.