# Two or three faces of $K_{\{3,3\}}$ on the torus?

Tags: graph-theory

Due to [Kuratowski's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem), graphs that contain the [Utility graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_utilities_problem) as a subdivision can't be drawn in the plane.
But on a genus $1$ surface, a torus! This is also resembled by [Euler's characteristic](http://www.weddslist.com/groups/genus/1/hex.php#0h2):
$$
\begin{array}{cCcc}
\chi =& 2-2g &=& V-E+F\, \\
&0 &=& 6 - 9 \, \,+ \,3
\end{array}
$$
We calculate $3$ faces!
Now, I found at least two "flat" representations of the torus:

[image] $\hskip{2cm}$ [image]

To the left (the Lord and) I see **two** squares and one surrounding face and to the right it rather looks like **three** squares and a hexagon...

> Why is that?

The hexagonal case needs another $180^\circ$ twist (["Indian Burn"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53454/wrapped-hexagon-topology)) to get the torus.

[image]

Is that relevant?

Comment: On the left, I see three faces.

Comment: Oh @Lord, thank you...

Comment: I don't know what an Indian Burn is (and I'm not going to chase it down), and I don't see the second diagram as giving a $K_{3,3}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson 1. a 180° twist on the tube before you close it (anon wrote that). 2. Choose a bipartition of the vertices, then every black vertex is connected to every white one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opps, I was wrong, with the right one. It just has **two** squares:

$\hskip{5cm}$[image]

To add something valueable, I found that the left torus is not strong embedded on the torus...

Comment: Can you please talk out what you mean by "strong embedded"?  I was really taken in by your claim that there were four faces in that embedding, and even now that I understand that there are three, it still looks like that "external face" is adjacent to itself.  I'm sure I could clear this up instantly if I owned a dry-erase torus, but I'm at the mercy of these diagrams.

Comment: @MatthewDaly from the linked reference: 
"Conjecture 1 (Strong  Embedding  Conjecture): Let $G$ be a $2$-connected  graph. Then  there  exists  an embedding of $G$ into a $g$-holed torus (for some $g$) such that the boundary of every face in the embedding is a cycle in $G$.

You  can  see  that  the  embedding  we  have  given  of $K_{3,3}$ (on the left) does  not  satisfy  this  requirement..."